# How to call servlet from a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Everything worked fine until I needed to use jar (inside WEB-INF>lib) file instead of **classes** in my **WEB-INF**. I have no idea how the html page calls the servlet from this jar file.

1. Do I need to add something to my web.ini file? please help.
2. I used Eclipse to make a jar file, where i checked only **build**. Is it correct?

My servlet.class location inside build is

> com.servlets.getData.class

Here is my web.ini

```
<display-name>crudoperation</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>upload</display-name>
    <servlet-name>upload</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servlets.getData</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>upload</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/upload</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what does your web.xml servlet declaration shows?

Comment: have you tried running it? does it shows any error?

Comment: @jigar: When i click on button to submit using js it does not do anything, neither does it show any error

Comment: @Harry: I tried it without using jar file. i.e., when the classes are inside the `classes` folder. It runs perfectly then.

Comment: can you access your servlet by making simple GET to `/upload`

Comment: @Abhishek: try after making jar file. Just try same thing when classes are in classes folder.

Comment: ya actually using post. Everything works fine when i used simple classes, I called my servlet for 3 requests and all requests gives proper response. But I have no clue what changes to make when I export my project to a jar file

Comment: @Harry: I tried the same thing when classes are in classes folder. It works fine

Comment: @Abhishek: Good. then what's the problem in that? It works when you have jar and when you have classes in folder.

Comment: @Harry: I am supposing, my jar contains all my classes, and my jar goes inside `WEB-INF>lib` folder so that way my classes folder don't need to have any classes. Is it correct?

Comment: @Harry: In my machine its ok, I can work with classes folder, what if I would like to give this app to someone else and just provide him with this jar.. something like this scenario

Comment: @Harry: Yes I can even do like that, but I've seen some people put all there class files in jar to give it to other machines so that there it can be used from the `lib` just like any other jar files. So i thought its a better way

Comment: @Harry: Sorry I did not understand, Is it correct whatever I am trying to do? Is the HTML supposed to call the classes from this jar file like my method?

Comment: @Harry: I even tried to manually enter servlet path `http://localhost:6060/app/upload` but it cannot find the servlet

Comment: @Harry: you are correct, i posted the problem that i was facing as an answer, because 1 answer needs to be there in order to accept this post :) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harry: You are right. The method that i am using is absolutely correct. I'll explain the problem that I was facing.

In my `WEB-INF>classes` i have this structure `com>servlets>getData.class` which works fine. But once I export my project builds into a jar and place it inside `{myproj}>WEB-INF>lib` folder I was renaming 'com>**servlets**' to **servlets1** (assuming now the web.ini will not be able to call getData from classes folder) this was the mistake, because it was able to look for `com` but then no `servlets` and i think it was totally ignoring my jar in lib folder.

So I totally removed my classes folder and now it works perfectly.